# What is the arithmetic flaw/contradiction in The Paradox of the Knower?

Tags: logic

I have linked and quoted from an article below, he states that there is some elementary contradiction based upon simple logic/arithmetic; I am failing to see the contradiction. Where/what is the contradiction?

From ["Problems with Omniscience" by Patrick Grim:](http://www.pgrim.org/articles/omniscience9.pdf)

page 3: "For any such system it is well known that we will be able to encode formulae recoverably as numbers. We will use A̅ to refer to the numbered encoding for a formula 
A. It is well known that for any such system we will be able to define a derivability relation I such that ⊢I(A̅, B̅) just in case B is derivable from A. Let us introduce a symbol '∇' within such a system, applicable to numerical encodings Ȧ for formulae A. We might introduce '∇' as a way of representing universal knowledge, for example—the knowledge of an omniscient being within at least the realm of this limited formal system. Given any such symbol with any such use we would clearly want to maintain each of the following:

If something is known by such a being, it is so ∇(A̅)→ A

This fact is itself known by such a being. ∇(∇(A) → A)

If B is derivable from A in the system, and A is known by such a being, B is known by such a being as well. I(A̅, B̅) →. ∇ (A̅) → ∇ (B̅)

The simple truth, however, well established as a logical theorem, is that no symbol can consistently mean what we have proposed '∇' to mean, even in a context as limited as formal as arithmetic. "

UPDATE-2: [simpler version of above update by the original author](https://books.google.com/books?id=0o_9Gs5LxyYC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=Omniscience+robinson+arithmetic+grim&source=bl&ots=vZEWf5MRs6&sig=q2CfllO4zrRILVToXGM7VrNuRC0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bIqDVa7YJseqsAXjubPQBw&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=Omniscience%20robinson%20arithmetic%20grim&f=false)

Comment: I don't quite understand the argument here but I generally don't see a problem with omniscience.  It's when you combine that with omnipotence that this becomes a problem (or if you wish to have free will--omniscience is not possible).  Omnipotence also isn't a problem (for me) on its own.  Ultimately, _all_ of these things depend on how exactly you define omniscience and/or omnipotence.  If we want to talk about these logically, then they must be defined precisely (which is very difficult to do).

Comment: I must say I have a problem with the following conclusion: _"Because
arithmetic is true, there is no omniscient being. Because arithmetic is necessarily true, no omniscient being is possible."_  This is wrong, one does not need to be omniscient to know that a [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology) is true (but certainly an omniscient being _would_ be aware of such tautologies by definition).  This seems to attack more the idea of omnipotence--i.e. a being cannot will a logical tautology to be _untrue_!

Comment: @Jared i am posting an update I found from another source, but its very logic symbol heavy and way over my head

Comment: I think it's also worth noting that pertaining to "gods", the religious folk tend to _not_ think of omniscience the same as a logician.  Rather, I would argue, most religious folk see omniscience as knowing every aspect of the state of the universe (i.e. "all-knowing" about what everyone and everything is doing).  This is _exactly_ the same as when I run physics simulations and me (via the computer) knows where every single particle is, its momentum, energy, etc. yet, if I introduce randomness into the simulation, I _still_ cannot predict the next state (assuming a chaotic system).

Comment: @Jared i posted a link of the explanation, is this explanation valid and what does it mean?

Comment: The problem with trying to write something in purely mathematical notation is that it's really only comprehensible to two types of people: 1) whoever wrote it and 2) the person who is willing to spend hours trying to decipher it.  Unfortunately, I'm not willing to do the second.  As a suggestion (if you ever intend to write technical papers) is that the mathematical proof is often _not_ what will convince people, it's the explanation in plain words.  Don't get me wrong, the mathematical notation is important--but only to see if you really proved what your plain words say you proved.

Comment: @Jared i found a simpler version of the previous update by the original author, maybe you can figure this one out quickly

Comment: In the final sentence of the quoted text, the author is simply pointing out that Godel's Incompleteness Theorem tells us that not all truths are derivable in the manner described.  Therefore, the existence of an omniscient being would stand in contradiction to Godel's result.

Comment: Based on what @NickR said (and a cursory glance of [Godel's First Incompleteness Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del's_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem)), it seems to me that perhaps the author is assuming that an omniscient being _can_ prove it's omniscient.  I think this assumes that one only knows a thing if they are able to prove it.  In fact many people "know" things they aren't able to prove (such as how a TV works--yet they "know" how to work a TV).  I don't think it's a necessary condition for an omniscient being to be able to prove it's omniscient.

Comment: @Jared could you elaborate a bit on what you're seeing from the 1st incompleteness theorem and perhaps make an answer out of it?

Comment: @NickR could you elaborate a bit on where you see Godel's theorem in the last line and perhaps make an answer? thanks

Comment: @Henry I don't think my elaboration would be relevant.  First, I do not fully understand Godel's Incompleteness theorem and second, I'm arguing from a more philosophical standpoint about what omniscience means.  I am arguing _not_ against the proof but against the _premise_ of the proof (i.e. what omniscience "means").  I'm not sure, but it appears to me that the proof relies on the idea that an omniscient being must _know_ the proof of their omniscience (which it appears Godel says is not _always_ possible--i.e. there are truths which cannot be proved).

Comment: @Henry Godel's Theorem is the "well established logical theorem" referred to by the author in the final sentence.  The theorem states that any formal theory (that includes arithmetic) necessarily includes true propositions which cannot be proven (deduced) in that theory.  In particular, according to this theorem, it is impossible to deduce all of the truths of arithmetic (and a whole lot more).

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this related argument.

The following assumptions are sufficient to prove the entailment: $\forall x (x \rightarrow \Diamond K x) \Vdash \forall x(x \rightarrow Kx)$ $-$ that is, that if it possible that every truth is knowable then every truth is in fact actually known.

(A) We assume a bi-valent, quantified modal logic powerful enough to express both the rule of necessitation (if $\vdash p$ then $\vdash \Box p$) and the duality of possibility and necessity ($\vdash \Box \sim p$ if and only if $\vdash \sim \Diamond p$).

(B) We assume the conjunction distributivity of the knowability predicate: whenever $\vdash K(p\&q)$ then $\vdash Kp \ \& \ Kq$.

(C) We assume that the predicate ``It is known by some agent that p", where `p' is a proposition, is factive: whenever $\vdash Kp$ then $\vdash p$.

(D) We assume that reasoning by proof-by-contradiction is valid: whenever $\vdash p  \rightarrow (q \ \& \ \sim q)$, then $\vdash \sim p$.

The proof is as follows.

\

(1) $\forall x (x \rightarrow \Diamond K x)$ [intial assumption]

(2)  $K(p \ \& \ \sim K p)$ \ \ \  [assumption for the purposes of a reductio, where $p$ is arbitrary]

(3) $Kp \ \&  \ K\sim K p$ \ \ \  [from (2) by the distribution of K]

(4) $Kp \ \&  \ \sim K p$  \ \ \ [(3) and the factivity of K on the right disjunct]

(5) $\sim (K(p \ \&  \ \sim K p))$ \ \ \ [contradiction on (4) and rejection of premise (2)]

(6) $\Box \sim (K(p \ \&  \ \sim K p))$ \ \ \ [rule of necessitation on (5)]

(7) $\sim \Diamond (K(p \ \&  \ \sim K p))$ \ \ \ [the duality of the modal operator from (6)]

(8) ($p \ \& \ \sim Kp) \rightarrow \Diamond K (p \ \& \ \sim Kp)$ \ \ \ [instance of (1)]

(9) $\sim (p \ \& \ \sim Kp)$ \ \ \ [by moduls tollens on (7) and (8)]

(10) $\forall x \sim (x \ \& \ \sim Kx)$ \ \ \ [by universal instantiation on (9) since $p$ was arbitrary]

(11) $ \forall x(x \rightarrow Kx)$ \ \ \ [by DeMorgan's on (10)]

Comment: Are you using [temporal logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#Temporal_operators)?  If not, can I suggest using a different notation (other than $\Diamond$ and $\square$)?

Comment: No. I am using using standard modal logic where $\Diamond$ and $\Box$ are understood as 'possible that...' and 'necessary that...' respectively.

See here for more details: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fitch-paradox/#ParKno

Comment: Fair enough then, once again, mathematical notations collide, lol.